# Sum value between overlapping interval slices per group

Tags: python, pyspark, intervals, overlap

I have a pyspark dataframe as below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession.builder 
         .master("local") 
         .getOrCreate())
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")

INPUT = {
    "idx": [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    "consumption": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 5.0],
    "valid_from": [
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-02 00:00:00+00:00", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-03 00:00:00+00:00", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-06 00:00:00+00:00", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00", tz="UTC"),
    ],
    "valid_to": [
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-02 00:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-05 00:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-05 00:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-08 00:00:00+0000", tz="UTC"),
        pd.Timestamp("2019-01-02 00:00:00+00:00", tz="UTC"),
    ],
}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(INPUT)
spark.createDataFrame(df).show()

>>>
   +---+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
   |idx|consumption|         valid_from|           valid_to|
   +---+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
   |  1|       10.0|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-02 00:00:00|
   |  1|       20.0|2019-01-02 00:00:00|2019-01-05 00:00:00|
   |  1|       30.0|2019-01-03 00:00:00|2019-01-05 00:00:00|
   |  1|       40.0|2019-01-06 00:00:00|2019-01-08 00:00:00|
   |  0|       5.0 |2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-02 00:00:00|
   +---+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

And I want to sum only `consumption` on overlapping interval slices per idx:

```py
+---+-------------------+-----------+
|idx|          timestamp|consumption|
+---+-------------------+-----------+
|  1|2019-01-01 00:00:00|       10.0|
|  1|2019-01-02 00:00:00|       20.0|
|  1|2019-01-03 00:00:00|       50.0|
|  1|2019-01-04 00:00:00|       50.0|
|  1|2019-01-05 00:00:00|        0.0|
|  1|2019-01-06 00:00:00|       40.0|
|  1|2019-01-07 00:00:00|       40.0|
|  1|2019-01-08 00:00:00|        0.0|
|  0|2019-01-01 00:00:00|        5.0|
|  0|2019-01-02 00:00:00|        0.0|
+---+-------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sequence](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sequence.html) to expand the intervals into single days, [explode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) the list of days and then [sum](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.sum.html) the `consumption` for each `timestamp` and `idx`:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

input=spark.createDataFrame(df)
input.withColumn("all_days", F.sequence("valid_from", F.date_sub("valid_to", 1 ))) \
    .withColumn("timestamp", F.explode("all_days")) \
    .groupBy("idx", "timestamp").sum("consumption") \
    .withColumnRenamed("sum(consumption)", "consumption") \
    .join(input.select("idx", "valid_to").distinct().withColumnRenamed("idx", "idx2"), 
        (F.col("timestamp") == F.col("valid_to")) & (F.col("idx") == F.col("idx2")), "full_outer") \
    .withColumn("idx", F.coalesce("idx", "idx2")) \
    .withColumn("timestamp", F.coalesce("timestamp", "valid_to")) \
    .drop("idx2", "valid_to") \
    .fillna(0.0) \
    .orderBy("idx", "timestamp") \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
input=spark.createDataFrame(df)...
+---+-------------------+-----------+
|idx|          timestamp|consumption|
+---+-------------------+-----------+
|  0|2019-01-01 00:00:00|        5.0|
|  0|2019-01-02 00:00:00|        0.0|
|  1|2019-01-01 00:00:00|       10.0|
|  1|2019-01-02 00:00:00|       20.0|
|  1|2019-01-03 00:00:00|       50.0|
|  1|2019-01-04 00:00:00|       50.0|
|  1|2019-01-05 00:00:00|        0.0|
|  1|2019-01-06 00:00:00|       40.0|
|  1|2019-01-07 00:00:00|       40.0|
|  1|2019-01-08 00:00:00|        0.0|
+---+-------------------+-----------+
```

Remarks:

- `sequence` includes the last value of the interval, so one day has to be [substracted](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_sub.html) from `valid_to`.
- the missing end dates of the intervals are then restored using a full join with the original `valid_to` values, filling up `null` values with `0.0`.